How to gather Twilio response in ASP.NET Core Web API?
I am trying to implement Twilio voice calls in C#. I have the following code which initiate a call:
    var accoutnSid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var authToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    TwilioClient.Init(accoutnSid, authToken);

    var to = new PhoneNumber("tonumber");
    var from = new PhoneNumber("fromnumber");

    var response = new VoiceResponse();

    response.Say("Hello, Please speak");

    response.Gather(
        input: new []{Gather.InputEnum.Speech}.ToList(), 
        timeout: 2, 
        action: new Uri("https://mywebapi.com/version/v0/routecalls/twilioresponse"), 
        method: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post);

    response.Say("Thanks for your input");

    var call = CallResource.Create(to: to, from: from, twiml: response.ToString());

When the user is done talking, per Twilio documentation below end point is called
https://mywebapi.com/version/v0/routecalls/twilioresponse

This is the code at the endpoint:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Twilio.AspNet.Common;
using Twilio.AspNet.Core;
using Twilio.TwiML;

namespace webapi.Controllers;

[ApiController]
public class TwilioCallsController : TwilioController
{
    public TwiMLResult twilioresponse(VoiceRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(request.ToString());
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        response.Say("You selected sales. Good for you!");
        return TwiML(response);
    }
}

The first part of the setup works fine, but when the user is done talking and I call the API end point, I get the following error at the API endpoint:

415 Unsupported Media Type

Could someone please let me know what am I doing wrong here?
